# Why am I getting undefined as the answer to this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the code to give whois details of a domain name

```
var whois = require('node-whois')

function Info() {

}
Info.prototype.dom =function () {
    whois.lookup('google.com', function (err, data) {

        })
    }
var k = new Info();

console.log(k.dom());
```

Comment: Can you provide a working JSFIDDLE?

Comment: whois.lookup uses callback. and you return nothing from dom()

Answer (score 1):

That's not really your problem.

Rather, the problem is that you don't deal with the non-blocking nature of JavaScript.  When you call k.dom() and it returns, the call to lookup has started, but it has not completed. The call does not wait ("block") for the answer.  Rather, when the answer eventually comes, the function you passed as the second argument to lookup is called with the results.  In that function, unfortunately, you do nothing, and so the return result is lost.

Try putting something inside of the function that prints out data and see what happens. Then think about how you will structure your code to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your script.js (module)

```
var whois = require('node-whois');

function Info() {

}
Info.prototype.dom = function (callback) {
    whois.lookup('google.com', function (err, data) {
        callback(err,data);
    });
}

module.exports = Info;
```

Using your script; Dont't use them in same file where you are defining your module shows bad practice.

```
var script = require('./script');
var k = new script();

k.dom(function(e,d){
    console.log(d);
});
```